# Can't run the jetty server

Tags: java, eclipse, jetty

I'm currently learning jetty. I copied some code from Jetty tutorial to embed jetty into java code.
Below is the code I use(copied from http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/embedding-jetty.html):
    package org.eclipse.jetty.embedded;

```
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server;
import org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler;

public class MinimalServlets {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Server server = new Server(8080);
    ServletHandler handler = new ServletHandler();
    server.setHandler(handler);
    handler.addServletWithMapping(HelloServlet.class, "/*");
    server.start();
    server.join();
}

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public static class HelloServlet extends HttpServlet {

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
        response.getWriter().println("<h1>Hello SimpleServlet</h1>");
    }
}

}
```

When I try to run this server in eclipse, it terminates immediately after I start it, but I thought it should keep running and listening for requests.

The external libraries I used are:

jetty-all-9.1.3.v20140225.jar,
javax.servlet.jar

The eclipse console log is as below:

2014-04-12 11:03:57.700:INFO::main: Logging initialized @189ms
9.1.3.v20140225

What is the problem here?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Tequila Thank you, there's no error reported by eclipse. It just terminated immediately after I start the server. But a web server should keep running until I stop it, right?